# How to tell JSLint / JSHint what global variables are already defined

Tags: javascript, global-variables, jslint, jshint

In my project we have some global variables that work as containers:

```
MyProject.MyFreature.someFunction = function() { ... }
```

So then I use that script across the site and JSLint / JSHint complains about that:

> 'MyProject' is not defined

I know that I can go to every JavaScript file and add the comment `/*global MyProject*/` on top of it. But I'm looking a way to define that comment in some sort of config file so I don't have to go file by file adding this comment.

Some kind on option in the `config/jshint.yml` would be nice.

Comment: Are you using the web applications (e.g. http://www.jshint.com/) or are you running them with node?

Comment: I'm using to run as a task with rake. Actually I'm using the jshint_on_rails

Comment: That explains the 'config/jshint.yml' file that I hadn't heard of.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For JSHint you can create `.jshintrc` to your project directory with

```
{
  "globals": { "MyProject": true }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But since I'm using jshint_on_rails, I can just set this option: predef: 'MyProject' on config/jshint.yml

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question :)

Comment: You are right, I missed that part. I will have in mind for the next time. Thanks

Comment: Just a small note on using this: put `false` for libraries like `angular` and `$`. But put this on `true` for globals you want to redefine yourself, like `myApp`.

Answer (score 64):

This is only for globals

```
/* global MyProject */
```

In your case you need

```
/* exported MyProject */
```

Comment: this is a good answer if you're working with one JavaScript file, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

JSLint has a textarea below the options that says `predefine global variables here` in it.  Just add the variable names in there before running the check.

JSHint doesn't allow you to add global variables, but you can uncheck the `When variable is undefined` option to suppress that warning.

The JSHint library also has parameters for globals, if you run it as a library . . . details in here: http://jshint.com/docs/

Comment: It doesn't sound like they're using the web interface - `But I'm looking a way to define that comment in some sort of config file so I don't have to go file by file adding this comment.` and `Some kind on option in the config/jshint.yml would be nice`

Comment: I've just found it, the 'predef' attribute under config/jshint.yml. it's a comma separated attribute.
Thanks!

Comment: Worth mentioning `predef` [exists in JSLint too](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L37).

Comment: Given Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials and a conventional hierarchy of solution folder and project sub-folders, you can put it in the solution root folder.

Comment: Undeserved downvotes. The question did not make it clear that Rails was being used until after this answer was left. +1